# NSNumberformatter add zeros to decimal part

Tags: objective-c, number-formatting

I'm looking for a way to display the following:

- "20000.5" => "20,000.50"
- "20000" => "20,000.00"

so basically always two decimals, adding an extra zero to decimal part if there is just one decimal

What would be the best way to do this? I know I can use NSNumberformatter but I keep getting "20000.9" => "20,000.9" not "20000.9" => "20,000.90"

Below is the code I have yet it does not work.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter2 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter2 setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[numberFormatter2 setGroupingSize:3];
[numberFormatter2 setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[numberFormatter2 setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
[numberFormatter2 setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter2 setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *theString = [numberFormatter2 stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1008977.2]];
NSLog(@"Number is: %@", theString);

---Number is: 1,008,977.2
```

- I wanted it to be 1,008,977.20

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for NSNumberFormatter? What code have you written? What did you set `minimumFractionDigits` to?

Comment: I set it to 2 but it didn´t work.

Comment: you have set the “maximum” fraction digits. Not minimum.

Comment: FYI - you are going to confuse many of your users around the world with your number formatting. Many people expect very different formatting than you are forcing here. Avoid setting specific grouping and decimal separators. Avoid setting specific grouping size. The only thing you should be setting is the min and max number of fraction digits.

Comment: Yes, it worked with minimum thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to add is:

```
[numberFormatter2 setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
```

This will give your desired output.

But please remove the following lines:

```
[numberFormatter2 setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[numberFormatter2 setGroupingSize:3];
[numberFormatter2 setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
```

Such fixed formatting will confuse many of your users.

Answer (score -1):

Your following code is error

*[numberFormatter2 setMaximumFractionDigits:2];*

change the code to the following sample

**[numberFormatter2 setMinimumFractionDigits:2];**

that means your output result can contain more than two decimal number.